# Battery life in dual-boot HTC HD2

Tags: battery-life, windows-mobile, htc-hd2, miui

I own a dual-booting HTC-HD2 with MIUI on SD card.

I already knew, from tutorials, that in order to maximize battery life I should first-boot Android only with 100% of charge.

This is currently unclear to me. First, I run Windows Mobile 90% of time, and I use Android occasionally only for some programs that are not available in WM.

It happened that I needed to boot Android when on the street, with less than 100% battery. However, I recently noticed that my battery is descharging really fast, for example today from 7:30am to 10am it ran from 100% to 68%, and I really wonder if it could have lasted till 8pm (when I get back home).

Is it because Android should **always** be booted with 100% of battery, or because I run 24/7 Skype and Windows Live Messenger in HSDPA from Windows Mobile?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is because at *first boot* (ie: inizialization), Android creates a Battery stat file to calibrate the battery.
After the first boot, you can start Android with any battery percentage.

If you think that after a long time, the battery percentage is not correctly reported, you can force Android to recreate the stats file with some root utilities available in the Market

Skype/MSN do draw a lot of battery, anyway, if you are using them from Windows Mobile, they are not running from Android.

You could try using [greenpower](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.gpo.greenpower&feature=search_result) or [juicedefender](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender&feature=search_result) to see if the data connection is the problem